# quasi-projective and separated as topological properties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a non-reduced noetherian scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Assume that $X^{red}$ is quasi-projective and separated, does the same hold for $X$  ?

(By the way, projective implies a priori separated, but this is not true for quasi-projective, right?)

any reference is welcome
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the reduction of a morphism is quasiprojective (or even projective), then the morphism itself need not be quasiprojective. See EGA II.5.3.5.

(Concerning your other question: Quasiprojective morphisms are separated. See EGA II.5.3.1.)